# Why do some SQL statements cause script failures even when not being executed?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I was running some SQL migration that first checked for some conditions to determine if it should be executed and I was surprised to discover that SQL server failed the script even in the case it was not executed. What was even more surprising - only broken INSERTs for existing tables caused the failure, while broken SELECTs and INSERTs for non-existing tables were not causing any failures.

Here is a minimalistic example.

The test table creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableWithManyColumnsTheFirstIsGuid](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

The test script:

```
IF 1 = 2 -- to never execute
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO NoSuchTable VALUES ('failure');
  SELECT * FROM NoSuchTable;
  INSERT INTO TableWithManyColumnsTheFirstIsGuid VALUES ('failure');
END
```

You will receive `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.` error, which is correct for the third command because there is no way for SQL server to insert a string value in a table with Guid and int columns.

**Why does it fail at all if that faulty INSERT statement would be never executed because of the `IF` condition?**

If the answer is 'because SQL server validates commands in scripts even when not executing them', then the question is why do the other two broken commands not cause it to fail?

This behavior can bite you hard in a situation when you have a migration that removes a column and a disabled old migration that inserts some data into that column. The disabled migration will cause your entire migration script to fail. Of course, you can clean up your migration, but that's manual work and not automation-friendly when using migration scripts generated by EntityFramework.

Is this behavior by design? Is it specified in ANSI SQL or is it Microsoft-specific?

Comment: Because SQL Server parses and compiles the entire script; you are seeing a compile-time error not a run-time error. This is normal and by design. you can work-around the error by using dynamic SQL and exec() to postpone compilation of desired script elements.

Comment: *"If the answer is 'because SQL server validates commands in scripts even when not executing them', then the question is why do the other two broken commands not cause it to fail?"* Because an object that doesn't exist doesn't cause a compile error, you can see if you run the statements in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5fbde30a1803cae88e2490da54a5cac) in SSMS, as the `PRINT` statements show in the messages pane. For a table that exists, however, the meta data is checked and this causes a compile error, as `TableWithManyColumnsTheFirstIsGuid` has 2 columns.

Comment: 'Because an object that doesn't exist doesn't cause a compile error' - this is very counterintuitive, not at all how other programming languages work. Wondering if it is by design and specified in ANSI SQL or specific to Microsoft.

Comment: A term you can use to find additional information is "deferred name resolution" if you are so inclined.

Comment: *"not at all how other programming languages work"* how programming languages work has nothing to do with it, SQL is *not* a programming language (the hint is in the name: **S**tructured ***Q**uery **L**anguage*). If you expect it to work like a programming language, then that is your first mistake. Comparing T-SQL to a language like C# is like comparing a Latin based language (English) to a Kanji based one (Japanese) and wondering why English grammar doesn't directly translate to Japanese. The languages are "built" very differently.

Comment: @Lamu I meant in a sense that other language compilers behave a bit more consistently - they will fail the same way if you access a variable that does not exist or a non-existing property on an existing object. Yeah, it can be compared to a culture shock, however, it's not about the meaning of the words but rather about how consistent the language is; and every language seems to have words that do not follow the general rules, like "go -> went" instead of "goed".

Comment: L a **r n** u... What other languages compilers? Again, a compiler for a programming language should not be expected to behave the same; if you are comparing to one for PL/SQL or PostgreSQL, sure, they would be more comparable. However, as @SMor mentioned, this is expected behaviour, and is called "deferred name resolution". It can be a very powerful tool; especially with objects like Stored Procedures that rely on Temporary Tables, or when deployed prior to their related objects.

Comment: @Larnu  I would not be so much surprised if it did not fail for all the three SQL commands, including also for the INSERT into a nonexisting column. Imagine a developer experimentally finding out they can have a script like INSERT and SELECT for NoSuchTable  - they would make a conclusion that you don't have to make sure your statements match the current database state... and then later be bitten by the fact that deferred name resolution does not work for columns but only for tables. It's inconsistent and breaks the "least surprise principle".

Comment: It's not inconsistent; deferred name resolution is "very* consistent. The fact that the behaviour you are used in in programming languages doesn't apply doesn't make it "not consistent". There is a wealth of information out there on the behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not yet find information that would satisfy my curiosity as to *why* deferred resolution accepts missing tables but does not accept missing columns. I'm very curious about the rationale for such implementation and who decided it. If someone knows the full story "behind the scenes" as to why this difference exists, I would accept it as an answer.

Comment: Just a guess but possibly it's only *object* names that are validated -  if an object exists, it's validated. A column is a property of an object, not an object itself.